# Hierarchical clustering with precomputed cosine similarity matrix using scikit learn produces error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering, cosine-similarity, distance-matrix

We want to use cosine similarity with hierarchical clustering and we have cosine similarities already calculated.
In the sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering documentation it says:

> A distance matrix (instead of a similarity matrix) is needed as input
>   for the fit method.

So, we converted cosine similarities to distances as

```
distance = 1 - similarity
```

Our python code produces error at the `fit()` method at the end. (I am not writing the real value of `X` in the code, since it is very big.) X is just a cosine similarity matrix with values converted to distance as written above. Notice the diagonal, it is all 0.) Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

X = np.array([0,0.3,0.4],[0.3,0,0.7],[0.4,0.7,0])

cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(affinity='precomputed')  
cluster.fit(X)
```

The error is:

```
runfile('/Users/stackoverflowuser/Desktop/4.2/Pr/untitled0.py', wdir='/Users/stackoverflowuser/Desktop/4.2/Pr')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-b8b98765b168>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/stackoverflowuser/Desktop/4.2/Pr/untitled0.py', wdir='/Users/stackoverflowuser/Desktop/4.2/Pr')

  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 100, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/Users/stackoverflowuser/Desktop/4.2/Pr/untitled0.py", line 84, in <module>
    cluster.fit(X)

  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/hierarchical.py", line 795, in fit
    (self.affinity, ))

ValueError: precomputed was provided as affinity. Ward can only work with euclidean distances.
```

Is there anything that I can provide? Thanks already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to sklearn's documentation:

> If linkage is “ward”, only “euclidean” is accepted. If “precomputed”,
>   a distance matrix (instead of a similarity matrix) is needed as input
>   for the fit method.

So you need to change the linkage to one of complete, average or single.

Answer taken from:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/51970/hierarchical-clustering-with-precomputed-cosine-similarity-matrix-using-scikit-l/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

n_clusters = Number of cluster needed.

linkage = Linkage can be `"complete"` , `"average"` or `"single"` for cosine affinity.

```
AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=n_clusters,affinity="cosine",linkage="average")
```